# uint32_t vs std::string comparison of IpV4 - performance

Tags: c++, performance, performance-testing

When comparing ip addresses I use to assume that comparasion of string is way slower than comparing uin32_t. As a result of avoiding that my code was sometimes more complex and less readable. However I started to wondering what's the real difference and decided to do quick benchmark. The result suprised me. Comparation string turnes out that both methods have the same speed. Now I'm not sure if I oversiplified the test or did something wrong. If not, why there is almost no difference? Comparing uint32_t vs uint32_t times x should not be equal.

```
static void IntIpV4Comparation(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  uint32_t ip1 = 100;
  uint32_t ip2 = 200;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    bool areEqual = ip1 == ip2;
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(IntIpV4Comparation);

static void StringIpV4Comparation(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  std::string ip1 = "127.0.0.1";
  std::string ip2 = "127.0.0.2";

  for (auto _ : state) {
    bool areEqual = ip1 == ip2;
  }
}
BENCHMARK(StringIpV4Comparation);
```

[image]

As expected the difference is also where is char makes string unequal. When it's in the middle there the result is oposite (but the difference is still such small). What's the edge case where diff may be the biggest?

Comment: Check the assembly. A quick play with the online compilers shows me (in release) it optimised out most/all of the code.  If you had posted a [mcve] I would include the link but I had to make more changes than I thought reasonable.

Comment: `uint32_t` is 4 bytes. String comparisons may be optimized to do comparisons in groups of 2-4 bytes when possible. Since your strings are identical for their 1st 8 bytes and only differ on their 9th byte, you may be getting better performance on the strings benchmark due to optimizations.

Comment: `bool areEqual = ip1 == ip2;` is a noop because result is not used and will be thrown away by any modern compiler. So you are not measuring comparison at all.

Comment: Add `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(areEqual);`

Comment: @rustyx After disabling result is how expected. Thanks.